# Simple JavaScript function returns function and not value

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out and I'm trying to build a simple calculation function that will display the result of 2 numbers on a page. When the submit button is hit the output is the function and not the value. Where have I gone wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="input">
<form id="start">
  <input id="price" type="number" placeholder="What is the starting price?" value="10">
  <input id="tax" type="number" value="0.08" step="0.005">
</form>
<button type="button" form="start" value="submit" onClick="total()">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
'use strict';

var total = function() {

  var price = function() {
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("price"));
  }

  var tax = function() {
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax"));
  }
  var final = function() {
    final = price * tax;
    final = total
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = final;

};
</script>
```

Comment: youre not returning anything from your functions

Comment: .... and `document.getElementById(...)` are references to those input elements, rather than their values.

Comment: You are declaring `final` as a function then redeclaring it as two different things within that function

Comment: From your code and all the comments I can see that you need to dig into Javascript basics before you continue to write code :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several issues with your javascript. Let's break them down one by one:

> ```
> var price = function() {
>     parseFloat(document.getElementById("price"));
> }
> ```

`document.getElementById` returns an element. `parseFloat` would try to calculate the element, and not the value in this case (Which would always be NaN or Not a Number). You want the value of this element, so using [`.value`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4173391/javascript-get-element-value) will return the value. Furthermore, you're not actually doing anything with the value. (You should use return to return the float found, or set it to another variable.)

> ```
> var final = function() {
>    final = price * tax;
>    final = total
> }
> ```

`price` and `tax` are both functions in this case. You can't simply multiply them to get your desired result. Using `var total = price() * tax();` will set the variable `total` to the float returned from `price()` and `tax()` now. Returning this value to the function will fix the next line:

> ```
> document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = final;
> ```

`final` here is also a function. You want to call it by using `final()`.

**Your final script:**

```js
var total = function() {

  var price = function() {
    return parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
  }

  var tax = function() {
    return parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value);
  }
  var final = function() {
    var total = price() * tax();
    return total
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = final();

};
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <form id="start">
    <input id="price" type="number" placeholder="What is the starting price?" value="10">
    <input id="tax" type="number" value="0.08" step="0.005">
  </form>
  <button type="button" form="start" value="submit" onClick="total()">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="output">test</div>
```

Comment: explaining the issues would make this a better answer rather than simply fixing them.

Comment: @Craicerjack Yup, I agree. Most users build up their answers.

Comment: Works great and the explanation is really awesome to help me understand what was happening!

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues, you put some code into function without calling them.

Another problem is, you need the value of the input tags.

```js
'use strict';
var total = function() {
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
    //                                           get value ^^^^^^
    var tax = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value)
    //                                       get value ^^^^^^

    // calculate directly the final value
    var final = price * tax;
   
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = final;
};
```

```html
<div id="input">
<form id="start">
  <input id="price" type="number" placeholder="What is the starting price?" value="10">
  <input id="tax" type="number" value="0.08" step="0.005">
</form>
<button type="button" form="start" value="submit" onClick="total()">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Great alternative solution, and simplifies what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score -2):

Delete

```
var final = function() {
    final = price * tax;
    final = total
  }
```

and instead put

```
return price * tax;
```

Comment: You are still not calling `price` and `tax` functions